# Excel autocomplete formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autocomplete

When I'm typing a long formula command in excel, like `sumproduct`, I can type '=s', and get a listbox with possibilities.
I want to direct with my arrow keys to the right formula and click on enter to autocomplete it to `sumproduct`.

I can't find out how to do this. Who knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing Tab will confirm the current selection and fill it in for you.

Comment: That was easier than I expected xD